# Python No module named, even though the module does appear

Tags: bash, python-2.7, module, pip, simplecv

Good day.

I've been using

```
pip install simplecv
```

to install the module simplecv.

I know the module was properly installed and when I'm printing list of the modules using

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2.7
    import pip
    installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
    installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
         for i in installed_packages])
    print(installed_packages_list)
```

I can see it in the list : 'simplecv==1.3'

But for some reason I can't use it. 
I've tried to export the path using

```
1) export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7"
2) export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
3) export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"
```

But nothing works

Any ideas?

Comment: "I can't use it": well, how are you trying to use it, and how is it failing?  Probably you think the module has a different name than it really does.

Comment: I keep on getting "no module named simplecv" error. I'm just trying to import it as simplecv, which is the name it appears by at the pip list ('simplecv==1.3')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *package* name isn't the same as the *module* name.  The module is called `SimpleCV`, as shown in [the documentation](http://tutorial.simplecv.org/en/latest/examples/shell.html).  So we have

```
>>> import simplecv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-2-064db77601b3>", line 1, in <module>
    import simplecv
ImportError: No module named simplecv
```

but

```
>>> import SimpleCV
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-3-d3da1d75bea1>", line 1, in <module>
    import SimpleCV
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SimpleCV/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from SimpleCV.base import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SimpleCV/base.py", line 59, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Cannot load OpenCV library which is required by SimpleCV")
ImportError: Cannot load OpenCV library which is required by SimpleCV
```

I didn't bother installing the dependencies, so this didn't work, but if I had, it would have. :-)

Comment: :) Indeed. I tried to capitalize it, But only as SimpleCv. I just didn't capitalize the V. Thanx!